# Enter on IME menu in IE, triggers keyup event on input

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, ime

I have an input on web page, which triggers search my hitting enter.

On GWT it looks like this

```
box.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent keyUpEvent) {
    if (keyUpEvent.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
      client.executeSearch();
    }
  }
});
```

When user from Japan uses IME:

He enters a word, hits space twice and sees a menu where he needs to chose the desired spelling. 
[Menu looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RZnv.png)
In Chrome and FF it works fine, but in IE, when user hits enter on desired spelling, keyUp handler on input is triggered.

So what I need is to preserve IE from triggering this ENTER on IME menu.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched `KeyUpHandler` to `KeyDownHandler`.
As far as I understand, pop-up menu is hiding by KeyDown event, so KeyUp was triggered on text Input.